# Kendo UI Grid - custom filter

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, grid

I would like to have custom filter on one of the grid columns, in the following way:

1. If the operator is 'is equal to' the user will be able to select a value from a 
   drop-down-list.
2. For the other operators (contains, start with etc.) the user will be able to enter a 
   free text.

can anyone explain me how to implement that?

Thanks

Hagai

Comment: Can you paste the code you have so far - are you using Kendo Grid with MVC/Web API

Answer (score 2):

There are several Grid features you should look into.  The first is "[columns.filterable.ui](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.filterable.ui)".  This allows you to display a custom editor in the filter popups.  Kendo-UI already shows different editors for string, number and date fields.  The second feature is the "[filterMenuInit](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#events-filterMenuInit)" event.  In it's handler you can look for the operator DropDownList and bind it's "[change](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/dropdownlist#events-change)" event where you can modify your custom editor based on the selected value.